# javascript get string out of parantheses match regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match, parentheses

I have a full string consisting of something like this [(data1.1)(data1.2)][(data2.1)(data2.1)]

Ive read you can do something smart with match function and regex. I want two arrays with the data loaded out of the parentheses.. How in earth do i do that? Please use my string as example.

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code so far.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this abomination:

```
var array = s.replace(/^\[|\]$/g,'').split('][').map(function(a){    
    return a.replace(/^\(|\)$/g,'').split(')(')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kLhc/

Also if you deliberately save or transmit data like this then you should really have a look at [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or proper database design.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't entirely sure what you were after, but I'm assuming this

```
var what = '[(data1.1)(data1.2)][(data2.1)(data2.2)]',
    have = [],
    you = [],
    tried = /\[\(([^)]*)\)\(([^)]*)\)\]/g;
what.replace(tried, function (use, brain, forthis) {
    you.push((have.push(brain), forthis));
});
console.log(have, you);
// ["data1.1", "data2.1"] ["data1.2", "data2.2"]
```